# ODP.NET XML Query with paging

Tags: c#, .net, xml, odp.net

I'm trying to migrate the following from an old classic asp vb app that uses an old version of non-managed oracle client and performs a .GetXML call which seems to pass in paging parameters.

However, in trying to get this working with the net ODP.NET managed nuget package there does not seem to be a direct conversion? Does anyone know what I'm missing?

```
    OraDynaset.XMLRowTag = "row"
   ' OraDynaset.XMLEncodingTag = "UTF-8" 
    OraDynaset.XMLEncodingTag = "iso-8859-1"
    OraDynaset.XMLNullIndicator = True

    XMLdata = OraDynaset.GetXML(clng(posStart), clng(count))

     If OraDatabase.LastServerErr <> 0 Then
        Session("OraXMLError") =  OraDatabase.LastServerErrText
        Session("OraXMLErrorSQL") =  QrySQL
        Response.end
     End If
```

The below is the new project

```
     using (var connection = new OracleConnection(this.connectionStringFactory.GetConnectionString()))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    AddParameters(cmd, parameters);

                    cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    cmd.BindByName = true;

                    cmd.XmlCommandType = OracleXmlCommandType.Query;

                    cmd.XmlQueryProperties.RowTag = "row";
                    cmd.XmlQueryProperties.RootTag = "rows";
                    cmd.XmlQueryProperties.MaxRows = -1;

                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
                    {
                        return XDocument.Load(reader, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
                    }
                }
            }
```